# Matplotlibs pyplot.subplots() crashes kernel

Tags: python, matplotlib

Using matplotlibs pyplot (in this case imported as plt) crashes my kernel (Py3.5 under Win7) when using more than 1 plot. More specifically, the axes obejct results in a crash. The crash is immediatly and killing all running python instances.

E.g. calling

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
```

crashes.
While

```
ret = plt.subplots(2,2)
fig = ret[0]
```

works, and then crashes when calling

```
ax = ret[1]
```

or

```
ax1 = ret[1][0]
```

or similar

Is this a known issue?

Answer (score 2):

I too faced a similar issue but I could get rid of the crashing problem using this way.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TKAgg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig,ax=plt.subplots(1, 1)
```

This worked for me. Give it a try.

Hope it helps.

Best Wishes

Comment: Not working for me